# BICC Extracts to GCP using Cloud Connector

Tags: oracle-fusion-apps

I am looking for a way to read data incrementally from the PVOs to the GCP. My initial hunch was to use Apache Airflow, but I think that would not serve the purpose. Later, I came across the BICC scheduled incremental extracts using the connector console but I am not able to locate any example to load data to GCS. I am not sure if BICC has that capability yet. Can someone guide me to any example that could help me meet the requirement?

Any help/guidance is appreciated.

[image]

- I went throguh the documentations but could not locate any way to connect to GCP
- the apprach to look for Apache Airflow did not also work as PVO are views combining multiple base tables and are exposed by BICC (Business Intelligence Cloud Connector) and we don't get access to the base Oracle tables directly